# Enabling mouse in Allegro5

Tags: c, allegro5

I am starting using Allegro in my program in C, but I'm having difficulties creating the buttons. I am using this kind of logic:

```
if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP)
{
      if ((event.mouse.x >= 442) &&(event.mouse.x <= 471) &&(event.mouse.y >= 202) &&(event.mouse.y <= 238))
            {
                dig = '1';
                entr = 1;
            }
```

But this spaces defined by the axis are non 'clickable'.Somebody here has some tip about the typo of command I should use?

Comment: Can you explain what you're expecting to happen, vs what actually happens? It's unclear from the small example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what was wrong, but there is no answer yet, so I will provide some tips about the possible problem. Your thread is titled enabling the mouse in allegro 5, so I can only assume you're not getting mouse input.

1) You need to install the mouse driver before you will get any mouse input :

`if (!al_install_mouse()) {Fail();}`

2) The mouse needs to be registered with your event queue.

`al_register_event_source(event_queue , al_get_mouse_event_source());`

In a typical GUI, most buttons are only considered 'pressed' if they receive both a mouse button down event over their click area, AND a mouse button up event over the same area. This way you don't get a button press when you click on something else, move the mouse over your button and release it. You also prevent button events from pressing the mouse, moving it off the click area and releasing it.